# App stuck on splash screen on second launch | Vuforia

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have an android app using Unity and Vuforia.

On one phone (Android version 11) it works great and I have no problems at all with the app.
On a different phone (Android version 13) everything works when I open the app, but when I close the app and reopen it, it just freezes and doesn't make it to the first scene.

When I reinstall the app or clear the cache, the same thing happens, everything works on the first time but when I close and reopen it, it freezes.

I suspect it has something to do with the camera permission pop up maybe.

I tried tweaking some settings in player and build settings, first the app froze always, but now it only works the first time I launch the app, and after that it freezes on future launches.

I tried launching it with a completely empty scene, or a scene with only a camera in it, but I don't think the problem is the scene, since it won't even reach the first scene.

Solution:

I found out the solution if someone runs into the same problem.
This worked for me: Player settings -> Other settings -> turn "Mute other audio sources" on.

Comment: I found out that when  I give camera permission, close the app, wait 10 seconds and then reopen the app, I get the camera permission message again, and it works.

But that means I would have to wait 10 seconds everytime I reopen the app, otherwise it doesn't work.

I also found out that when I deny camera access the app works, so I can open close and reopen the app as many times I want and the app opens without trouble, but the app needs to use the camera so that's not an option because when I do give access, I have to wait 10 seconds.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.